# Filtering with the "AND" operator not working as expected in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter data from a CSV file.  There are 3 Columns OS1, OS2, and OS3.  If any these 3 cells are anything but yes I need that row exported to another CSV file.  Here is what I came up with:

```
$OSCOL = Import-csv $pwd\$Source\Win.csv | `
where {$_."OS1" -inotmatch "Yes" `
-and $_."OS2" -inotmatch "Yes" `
-and $_."OS3" -inotmatch "Yes" } `
| Export-Csv $pwd\ossla.csv -notypeinfo
```

However this is not working as expected...  If 'any' of the cells are not 'Yes' then that row is not exported.  So for example if my csv File is:

```
    servername,OS1,OS2,OS3
    serv1,yes,no,no
    serv2,yes,Yes,yes
    serv3,pending,yes,yes
    serv4,no,pending,no
```

I would want the output of:

```
    servername,OS1,OS2,OS3
    serv1,yes,no,no
    serv3,pending,yes,yes
    serv4,no,pending,no
```

However I what I am getting is:

```
    servername,OS1,OS2,OS3
    Serv4,no,pending,no
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got that logic backwards there.

What you want to test for is whether *all* cells match `Yes` and then grab those objects if that's *not* the case:

```
Import-Csv $PWD\$Source\Win.csv |where {-not(
$_."OS1" -match "Yes" -and 
$_."OS2" -match "Yes" -and 
$_."OS3" -match "Yes")}
```

Comment: Technically you'd want to use `-eq` over `-match` here in case some of the "not yes" values include the word "yes" (currently this would interpret something like "yesyes" as a match to "yes" but I'm assuming that "yesyes" should be exported.)

Answer (score 1):

Your logical `-and` is the error, if any one different than Yes should trigger output you'll need to use `-or`.
In your sample only the line where all 3 cols are not Yes are output.
Btw: you don't need to escape the line end following a pipe symbol. I changed this script which now needs no backticks.

```
$OSCOL = Import-csv .\Win.csv |
   where {$_."OS1" -inotmatch "Yes" -or
   $_."OS2" -inotmatch "Yes"  -or
   $_."OS3" -inotmatch "Yes" } |
     Export-Csv .\ossla.csv -notypeinfo
```

Output

```
> cat .\ossla.csv
"servername","OS1","OS2","OS3"
"serv1","yes","no","no"
"serv3","pending","yes","yes"
"serv4","no","pending","no"
```